# react redux - TypeError: actionName is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux. I am trying to get a basic application going. I have read the docs, but I still am having problems. I am getting the error message `NameOfMyAction is not a function.` This only happens after I fill in the form and attempt to submit it to redux by clicking submit.The error that I am getting specifically is `TypeError: addSodaDrink is not a function` . I'll list my setup below since I don't know what else to say about it.

// index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {store} from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

// app.js

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { addSodaDrink} from './redux/actionCreators/drinkActions';
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: ""
  }
  handleAddSodaDrink = () => {
    const {addSodaDrink} = this.props;
    addSodaDrink(this.state.input);
  }
  handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState(({...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.sodas.map(soda => {
            return (
              <p>{soda}</p>
            )
          })
        }
        <input name="input" type="text" onChange={this.handleInput} />
        <button onClick={this.handleAddSodaDrink}>Add Soda</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    sodas: state.sodas
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addSodaDrink: dispatch(addSodaDrink)
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

// actions

```js
import { ADD_SODA_DRINK } from "../constants/drinkConstants";

export const addSodaDrink = (drink) => ({type: ADD_SODA_DRINK, payload: drink })
```

// reducers

```js
import { ADD_SODA_DRINK } from '../constants/drinkConstants';

const defaultState = {
    sodas: [],
    alcoholic: [],
    water: []
}

export const drinkReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case  ADD_SODA_DRINK:
            const newSodas = state.sodas;
            newSodas.push(action.payload);
            return newSodas;
        default:
            console.log(action);
            return state;
    }
}
```

// store.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { drinkReducer } from "./reducers/drinkReducer";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from "redux-logger";

const composedEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(logger, thunk))

export const store = createStore(drinkReducer, composedEnhancer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your addSodaDrink in your mapDispatchToProps as a function.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addSodaDrink:(input) => dispatch(addSodaDrink(input))
  }
}
```

Another easier way is to have your actions in the mapDispatchToProps as an object .

[mapDispatchToProps as Object](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object)

We have an object in the state but you are trying to return an array in the reducer for the action `ADD_SODA_DRINK`

```
export const drinkReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case  ADD_SODA_DRINK:
            const updatedSodas = [ ...state.sodas, action.payload ];
            const updatedState = { ...state, sodas: updatedSodas }
            return updatedState;
        default:
            console.log(action);
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: that seemed to fix my problems with that but now i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Edited my answer for the error fix - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`